# table header is repeating from a for loop in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a leaderboard from a database. I have the data printing out in a list. when i try to put this data in a html table the header is repeating itself after each data entry. It is the for loop causing this but i cant figure out how to just have the header printing once and the data being inserted in each row after that. any help would be greatly appreciated. The code and a screen shot of the result is below.
Thak you in advance.

```
    <?php
require_once 'header.php';
    // Send variables for the MySQL database class.
    $database = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('robinsnest') or die('Could not select database');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER by `quiz_score` DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

    $num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);  

    for($i = 1; $i <= $num_results; $i++)
    {
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
         echo "<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>User Name</th>      
    <th>Score</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>".$i."</td>
    <td>".$row['user']."</td>       
    <td>".$row['quiz_score']."</td>
  </tr>

</table>";
    }
    echo '<footer>
                <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
                <p>&copy; 2014 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
            </footer>';
?>
```

The result is The "position, user Name and score headers repeated after each loop through the users name and score"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove Header from loop.

Do like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'header.php';
    // Send variables for the MySQL database class.
    $database = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('robinsnest') or die('Could not select database');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER by `quiz_score` DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

    $num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);  

    echo "<table>
          <tr>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>User Name</th>      
           <th>Score</th>
           </tr>";

    for($i = 1; $i <= $num_results; $i++)
    {
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

         echo "<tr>
              <td>".$i."</td>
              <td>".$row['user']."</td>       
              <td>".$row['quiz_score']."</td>
              </tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";

    echo '<footer>
                <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
                <p>&copy; 2014 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
            </footer>';
?>
```

Let me know for more help !!

Comment: Thank you it worked!! I was going along the same lines but left the closing table tag in side of the loop. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php
    require_once 'header.php';
    // Send variables for the MySQL database class.
    $database = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('robinsnest') or die('Could not select database');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `members` ORDER by `quiz_score` DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

    echo '<table>
        <tr>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>User Name</th>      
        <th>Score</th>
        </tr>';

    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>
        <td>".++$i."</td>
        <td>".$row['user']."</td>       
        <td>".$row['quiz_score']."</td>
        </tr>";
    }

    echo '</table>';
    echo '<footer>
                <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
                <p>&copy; 2014 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
            </footer>';
?>
```

And let me know, if there is any issue.